# Does "in" mean "during"?

Tags: word-choice

Would it be correct to say that "in the exam" can mean 1. "during the exam", 2. "on the exam" =in the exam paper, 3. "at the exam"=location?
For example,

1. "I answered the examiner's questions in the exam." During.
2. "I answered the examiner's questions on/in the exam." In the exam paper.
3. "I answered the examiner's questions in the exam." Location.

Are my sentences correct?

Comment: If you *answered the examiner's questions **on** the exam*, that would normally mean he'd asked you questions ***about*** the exam (an unlikely scenario). But note that preposition ***in*** is potentially vague / ambiguous in your cited example anyway. It could imply ***during** [the time period within which you were taking the exam]*, OR it could imply "location" (in *either* your completed exam answer papers, or the location where the exam was held). Also note that it's ambiguous as to whether the examiner's questions were ***posed*** within the exam, or somewhere else.

Comment: I read this explanation below on the internet. Does the use depend on each native speaker?

Comment: We can use on the exam in "On the exam there was a question about xxxxx". This is short for exam paper and perhaps should not count, since we could also say in the exam. You can also "score high marks/in on the exam".

Other example of prepositions depend on the surrounding words  and are not normally used with exam.

Comment: Does this mean that "in" can mean "during the exam" , it can refer to the exam paper to what was in it, and ("on" is also  used instead of "in" as it is mentioned by  the native speaker )and even to the location of the exam?

Comment: All of those (and doubtless several more) are possible "meanings" to ***in*** when used with something like an ***exam***. Up to and including the possibility that the examiner asked the speaker some questions during an exam conducted at some point in the past (maybe *years* ago), and speaker is simply reporting that he has just provided the answers to those questions (but perhaps the examiner hasn't and never will get to see those answers).

Comment: ..and even to the location of the exam as you said.

Comment: Which would be the best option to choose to say that last week during an exam I was asked a question and answered it. Which is preferred by native speakers?

Comment: I mean "in" or "during"?

Comment: Yes. The "target" of ***in*** could be the act of answering, the examiner, or the exam itself. And the "scope" of the preposition could refer to the period of time during which the exam took place, or the text of the exam (questions *read* by the speaker, OR answers *written* by him). And probably it can mean other things that haven't specifically occurred to me yet.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "last week during an exam I was asked a question and answered it". Was the question posed within the exam paper, or did someone come up and talk to you? Did you answer on the exam ***output*** paper, or in some other way?

Comment: This is a fairly pointless line of enquiry. You must know by know that English prepositions are very flexible. Which isn't normally a problem, because context usually makes it obvious exactly what's meant, and if not you can normally ask the speaker for clarification. Asking exactly what a relatively simply utterance "means" in a relatively contextless situation isn't going to teach anyone much.

Comment: I meant for example, the examiner asked me  two questions. One was in the exam paper and the other was asked by the examiner himself.

Comment: No! Believe me it's not pointless at all. You helped me a lot!

Comment: In the situation I described what would be a native speaker's choice?

Comment: In all cases, during the exam. He asked me a question from the exam. is the other meaning.

Comment: *He asked me a question [taken] **from** the exam* would normally mean the question he asked you ***came from*** (or ***will come from***) the exam, but that within the context in which he asked you, you weren't otherwise interacting with the exam (you weren't taking it as a text, and you didn't have it in your possession for reference; only the other person had access to it at thetime of asking you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your examples are not incorrect, but they are not very specific. So it's not that "in" *means* during, but it can be used when you mean during. Or "in" can be used when the speaker/writer means other things.

So if you want to clearly communicate a specific meaning, you might want to use a more specific preposition, and/or specify whether you mean an exam paper, period, room, or something else.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!